# Increase website performance or preload mp4/gif backgrounds

Tags: performance, load, gif, mp4

Is there any way to preload MP4/GIF background assets? Or is there a way to increase the website load time with MP4/GIF used as a background image?

Answer (score 0):

So, the way that I do it:

1. Create another HTML document, name it something like `video.html` with contents something like this:

   ```
   <video autoplay="" loop="" poster="bg.jpg" id="bgvid">
       <source src="image/background.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   </video>
   ```

   (where bg.jpg is a screencap of the first frame of the video, and background.mp4 is the actual video)
2. In your main HTML, create a div with the id of `background` and leave it empty. In your CSS, give the div a background that is the same as the first frame of the video (screenshot it or something)
3. Next, use some Javascript (with JQuery) like this:

   ```
   $(window).bind("load", function() {
       $('#background').load('video.html');
   });
   ```